# Xcode (interface builder) is changing darkTextColor to calibrated RGB 0,0,0,1. Is this a bug?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uicolor

This is being bugging me for a while. Sometimes when I open a file in Xcode - Interface builder. The files gets automatically changed. The change is basically worthless since it is changing `darkTextColor` and `groupTableViewBackgroundColor` (and possibly others) to their absolute values.

This time I am opening the file with the new Xcode 6.4 but this has happened in the past too. Sometimes I commit the changes, sometimes I ignore. What is the correct thing to do here? Is this a bug?

I am worried about cases like `groupTableViewBackgroundColor`, where they could slightly change in the future and I would like my app to adopt the latest colour when opened in the lastest Xcode. I am not sure if this is going to happen if I commit the absolute values.

```
diff --git a/CompanyApp/CompanyApp/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard b/CompanyApp/CompanyApp/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
index bf84644..775e1ac 100644
--- a/CompanyApp/CompanyApp/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
+++ b/CompanyApp/CompanyApp/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
-<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="7706" systemVersion="14D136" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" initialViewController="az4-Gy-rAe">
+<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="7706" systemVersion="14E46" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" initialViewController="az4-Gy-rAe">
     <dependencies>
         <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="7703"/>
         <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
@@ -12,7 +12,7 @@
                     <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="grouped" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="66" sectionHeaderHeight="10" sectionFooterHeight="10" id="HFW-La-Q8Y">
                         <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="504"/>
                         <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
-                        <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="groupTableViewBackgroundColor"/>
+                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.93725490196078431" green="0.93725490196078431" blue="0.95686274509803926" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                         <prototypes>
                             <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" accessoryType="disclosureIndicator" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="EventCell" rowHeight="66" id="6lU-wJ-yCt" customClass="EventCell">
                                 <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
@@ -98,7 +98,7 @@
                                                 <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="2015/8/7" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="tRX-TK-pDN">
                                                     <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                     <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="16"/>
-                                                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
+                                                    <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                                     <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                 </label>
                                             </subviews>
@@ -115,7 +115,7 @@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a *feature* of Xcode so my app always looks the same as design time. So I am committing the changes.

Comment: I have just had exactly the same thing happen. I'm not sure how this rates as a feature, but it does seem to render the idea of a 'darkTextColor' redundant. I wouldn't be surprised if 'darkTextColor' doesn't vanish as a concept some time in the near future.